# Gradient descent algorithm not converging

Tags: matlab, adaptive-filters, optimization, adaptive-algorithms, gradient

I wish to use the gradient descent algorithm to minimize the cost function

$$J(\mathbf{w}) = (\mathbf{w} - \mathbf{w}_{o})^{T} \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{w} - \mathbf{w}_{o})$$

where $\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, $\mathbf{w}_{o} = (-2, 2)^{T}$ and $\mathbf{A} = \textrm{diag}(20,1)$.

In MATLAB, starting with an intialization $\mathbf{w}^{(0)} = (5, 15)^{T}$ and a step size $\mu = 0.09$, I run the algorithm until $||\mathbf{w} - \mathbf{w}_{o}||^{2} < 0.001$.

However, when the algorithm finishes, I end up getting a NaN in the final weight vector. What could be the reason behind this?

For this algorithm to converge, the step size must lie in the range $\left(0, \frac{2}{\lambda_{max}}\right)$ where $\lambda_{max} = 20$ is the maximum eigen value of $A$, and this is indeed the case.

Given below is the code

```
close all

% cost function
J = @(w1,w2) 20*(w1+2).^2 + (w2-2).^2;


%% gradient descent algorithm
w = [5 15]'; % init.
mu = 0.09; % step size
wo = [-2 2]'; % final
iterGD = 0; % iterations
while norm(w-wo)^2 > 0.001

    w = w - mu*[40*(w(1)+2); 2*(w(2)-2)];
    iterGD = iterGD + 1;

end
wGD = [w(1); w(2)];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your step size is too large. The upper limit $2/\lambda_{max}$ for the step size $\mu$ is valid if the update is defined as

$$\mathbf{w}_{k+1}=\mathbf{w}_{k}-\frac{\mu}{2}\nabla J(\mathbf{w}_k)$$

The way you defined the update, the upper limit is too large by a factor of $2$. With `mu = 0.045` your code should work like a charm.